# Is Radeon Dynamic Power Management Enabled By Default By Now?

Tags: ati, graphics, radeon, open-source

I keep reading that it is, that it isn't. That it was supposed to be enabled by default in the Linux kernel version 3.13 or 3.14, or in Ubuntu 14.04. Or do you still have to follow [these steps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver#Power_Management) to enable it?

I'm considering upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 just for this feature.

It's just hard to find a straight answer online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Dynamic Power Management is enabled by default in Ubuntu 14.04. It was actually enabled upstream in Linux 3.13.